# How to remove bracketed term from string in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `[[a] bcd]`, and I want to extract just the `bcd` from it. How do I do this in Javascript?

Comment: filter whatever is not an array

Comment: `[[a] bcd]` is this an array ? or what?

Comment: This isn't an array. It's just a plain string.

Comment: This is pretty vague. What is the specification? There are so many ways to do this and there's no telling which is more appropriate than another for your use case without additional details, `s.slice(4, 8)`, `s.match(/bcd/)`, `s.match(/\w+(?=\]$)/)`, `[...s.matchAll(/\w+/g)].pop()`... Can the brackets by arbitrarily nested? What's special about `bcd` exactly that makes it a candidate for matching? Have you tried writing code yet? Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is the combination of both a negative look-ahead (on the inner array), and a positive look-ahead (on the final closing `]`). This can be seen in the following:

```js
const str = '[[a] bcd]';
const regex = /(?!\[.+\])([a-z]+)(?=]$)/g;
const matches = str.match(regex); // Array of matches

console.log(matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a regex replacement with callback function here, to strip away any nested bracketed content inside the outermost brackets:

```js
var input = "[[a] bcd]";
var output = input.replace(/\[(.*)\]/, function(match, contents, offset, input) {
        return contents.replace(/\[.*?\]|\s+/g, "");
    }
);
console.log(output);
```

To understand how this works, the first regex replace captures all content inside the outermost square brackets, which is `[a] bcd`.  We then pass this content to a callback function, which in turns strips away all bracketed content or whitespace, leaving behind just `bcd`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"[[a] bcd]".match(/(?<=\[).*(?=\])/)[0].replace(/\[\w*?\]/,"").trim();
```

1. Return the match of the elements inside [ and ].
2. Return the match inside the first element under [ and ].
3. Replace found result of 2 from 1.
4. Trim spaces.